# java.util.MissingResourceException:

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I have 2 java Applications, 2nd application is added as jar file to the 1st one and the 1st application is deployed as a workflow in JBOSS.

2nd application is having a .property file not included in the jar. So now ultimately I have not included that .property file anywhere and so I am getting the missing resource exception.

Question here lies is, where should I place that .property file. With my little experience on TOMCAT, I know I have to place that somewhere in JBOSS config. Version of JBOSS is 7.

Please help me with this. I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

This post has helped me: [java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name 'property_file name', locale en_US](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142002/java-util-missingresourceexception-cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-property-fi). Just placed the file in configuration folder of JBOSS and added the qualified name.