# MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name

Tags: java, netbeans

[this is my working tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJdSj.png)

```
Object selecao = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
if(selecao.equals("English")){
    //Locale local = new Locale("en", "EN");
    this.bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Presentation.Bundle", Locale.UK);
    this.jLabel1.setText(bundle.getString("IdiomaUI.jLabel1.text"));
    this.confirmarBt.setText(bundle.getString("IdiomaUI.confirmarBt.text"));
    this.cancelarBt.setText(bundle.getString("IdiomaUI.cancelarBt.text"));
}else if(selecao.equals("Português")){
    this.bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("Presentation.Bundle");
    this.jLabel1.setText(bundle.getString("IdiomaUI.jLabel1.text"));
    this.confirmarBt.setText(bundle.getString("IdiomaUI.confirmarBt.text"));
    this.cancelarBt.setText(bundle.getString("IdiomaUI.cancelarBt.text"));
}
```

I'm getting the error: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name Presentation.Bundle, locale pt_PT":

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name Presentation/Bundle, locale pt_PT
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
>       at Presentation.IdiomaUI.jComboBox1ActionPerformed(IdiomaUI.java:136)
>       at Presentation.IdiomaUI.access$000(IdiomaUI.java:17)
>       at Presentation.IdiomaUI$1.actionPerformed(IdiomaUI.java:56)
>       at javax.swing.JComboBox.fireActionEvent(JComboBox.java:1258)
>       at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedItem(JComboBox.java:586)
>       at javax.swing.JComboBox.setSelectedIndex(JComboBox.java:622)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicComboPopup.java:834)
>       at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:290)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicComboPopup$1.processMouseEvent(BasicComboPopup.java:498)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

I've already searched about this and i haven't figured it out what the problem is. Help please!

Comment: post the complete stacktrace of the error.

Comment: done! i'm also getting the same error with the Bundle_en_GB.properties.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Locale` is set to Portuguese then the `ResourceBundle` will attempt to load content from a properties file called `Bundle_pt_PT.properties`. According to the screenshot you don't have this in your project.

Take a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/propfile.html) for more information on ResourceBundles/localisation in Java
And [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html) for some general information on supported Locales.

Comment: But i'm also getting the same error with the Bundle_en_GB.properties.
The Bundle.properties file is suposed to be the default properties file, which is in this case Portuguese.

Comment: Ensure you are using a fully qualified path. See the answers for this SO question for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142002/java-util-missingresourceexception-cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-property-fi