# Can't find bundle for base name /Bundle

Tags: java, android

help 
When I try to run my project, it show following exception massage..

> Error:Android Source Generator: Error: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale fr_FR
>   java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name messages.AndroidJpsBundle, locale fr_FR
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException(ResourceBundle.java:1564)
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl(ResourceBundle.java:1387)
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle(ResourceBundle.java:773)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.getBundle(AndroidJpsBundle.java:22)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsBundle.message(AndroidJpsBundle.java:32)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.runAaptCompiler(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:971)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.doBuild(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:210)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.build(AndroidSourceGeneratingBuilder.java:114)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1263)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:940)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1012)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:903)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:736)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:384)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:192)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:138)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:295)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
>       at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: [duplicated issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142002/java-util-missingresourceexception-cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-property-fi)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name 'property\_file name', locale en\_US](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142002/java-util-missingresourceexception-cant-find-bundle-for-base-name-property-fi)

Comment: jibrahim, the issue you pointed is 2013, but the current problem conserns Android Studio update to 3.0, unfortunately. No solution yet